# Define Custom Rule to allow traffic based on queryString value

Tags: nginx-ingress

In nginx, I have few owasp rules disabled for my ingress as below

`Include /etc/nginx/owasp-modsecurity-crs/nginx-modsecurity.conf SecRuleEngine On SecRuleRemoveById 920210 920230 920420 920440 920350 930120 930100 930110 941331 941130 941150 941160 941340 942370 942360 942330 942340 942260 942200 942120 942110 942430 942190 942380 942440 932100 931130`

I would now want to allow a traffic if the queryString contains a value - say 'qwerty'. How do i achieve this .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create some kind of a firewall bypass (for example for testing purposes), you can use a rule similar to this:

```
SecRule ARGS_GET:password "@streq secret_password" \
    "id:100,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    t:none,\
    msg:'Bypassing firewall for %{REMOTE_ADDR}',\
    ctl:ruleEngine=Off"
```

Replace secret_password with your password and use like

```
https://example.com/?a=/etc/passwd&password=secret_password
```